# Some form of Progress bar when something is loading in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, ajax

Is there a easy way to show some form of progress bar on your form in ASP.NET that the code is busy running in the background (meaning thinking)? Like the default I.E have the small little window on the top that moves when its thinking..........

I have done this before with Ajax but its alot of work and my site is not a Ajax enabled site.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has a progress bar component, might be worth a look.

Comment: Any example or link to an example?

Comment: I gave a link to the JQuery UI homepage:-) Try this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the jQuery plugin [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/).  Pretty easy to set up and very cool looking, especially when used with [jgrowl](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html).